# Why SVN makes read-only my files after check out or update?

Tags: svn

Working with an standard configuration of the server, without any lock, my files are read-only after every check out or update to the working copy. I have to set them to be not read-only to continue working, but besides this shouldn't be happening, it's uncomfortable.

Anybody knows how to avoid this behavior?

**EDIT**

Answers to comments:

- Platform: Windows 32 bits binding, without Apache + TortoisseSvn.
- The files are not marked as read only on the first checked in to the repository (of course!, if they were this question would be silly)
- I don't think that it would be incompatibility, because it was working fine until *it wasn't*...
- The svn:needs-lock property is not set on the files.
- I'm using a local NTFS file system on WinXP, in an Active Directory environment (if that matter).

By the way, svn+tortoissesvn was working fine in the beginning, but at some point it stopped to do that.

Comment: This has never happened to me - the SVN metadata files are readonly, but never the working copy.  What platform - server and client?  Which client software?

Comment: Were the files read only when you first checked them in to svn? They are probably marked read only in the repository

Comment: could be incompatibility between the SVN server and the client version you use. Make sure they are both compatibility or both up to date

Comment: @Sam Post - Subversion does not version file properties.  So, it does not matter if it is read-only when you check it in.

Answer (score 3):

Is the svn:needs-lock property set on the files in question?

http://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.5/svn.advanced.locking.html

http://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.5/svn.ref.properties.html

**UPDATE**

AFAIK, SVN will only set files as read-only if svn:needs-lock is set.  If this property truly is not set, then something else on your system may be messing with the files.  You could use Process Monitor to watch the files and see who changes them.