# svn checkout files are read only

Tags: svn

I am new to svn. I just set up a repository on my server which is an old desktop computer that I do not use anymore. I installed Ubuntu. Right now, my question is that my friend made a svn checkout on his side but was not able to edit files and commit files because the files are read only. Is there way to make them read-write in the properties setting? Thank you. We are using Mac and do everything in command line.

Comment: One reason that a file might checkout as readonly is if the repo is setup to require locking of files. Try `svn lock my_file` and see if that works and makes a file in the checkout writeable.

Answer (score 0):

It's not an SVN issue, but OS. A working copy is a set of files on a computer, so try to use `chmod` and make them writable.

Comment: I see...I was under the impression that svn checkout files should set to read write originally. Thanks a lot.

Comment: Just a question tho, would it be the same to all other usrs? I mean, the files that I checkout are read write, but my friend's copy is read only. Is it because my mac and server sharing the same IP address??

Comment: I don't think so. The checkhed out files get the privileges from the user who executes svn command. Your system and your friend's system are different systems or are you using the same computer? You are sharing the server IP because your computer IS the server (otherwise I don't know what do you mean with share the IP address)? Check also for the needs-lock property in files as mentioned here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2492306/why-svn-makes-read-only-my-files-after-check-out-or-update

Comment: We are using different system. I was trying to find the needs-lock property but do not where to find. All the post are talking about using tortoiseSVN or Windows system. None of them talks about how or where to find it in Linux system.

Comment: Try 'svn proplist file.ext' and see if there are some properties (it may not be so), and if there are, check for the needs-lock presence.